# c# wpf Datetime changed (New day has come) event

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello guys I trying to do something like this to create event which starts to do something when new date has came like it was 2014/01/01 and it is  2014/01/02 and then do some stuff :

```
private void Datetime.now_changed(days)(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           do some stuff;
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: What do you want to do? Why don't you simply add a scheduled task in Windows to run once a day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a class for checking the day change:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;


public class Clock
{
    private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer(1000);
    private DateTime _yesturday = DateTime.Today;

    public event EventHandler NewDay;

    public Clock()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_yesturday != DateTime.Today)
        {
            if (NewDay != null) NewDay(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            _yesturday = DateTime.Today;
        }
    }


}
```

Now we can use:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = new Clock();
        c.NewDay += OnNewDay;
    }

 private void OnNewDay(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // new day comes
    }
```

Comment: Great solution but there is a bug. you need to stop the timer just before posting the event and start the timer again just after re-assigning the new _yesturday. The reason is if the event receiver calls a function that runs longer than 1 second it will get a double event. stopping and starting will eliminate this possibility.

Comment: Also since this is a WPF thread, why not use a DispatcherTimer instead? The normal timer sends the event on a different thread than the UI. If you use a DispatcherTimer instead the even is on the UI thread and so the event receiver can update UI components without having to do an Invoke first. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a scheduled task is probably your best way of action. If not you can (in theory) use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class set to whatever time is left till 00:00:00. Usually it makes sense on shorter timespans, like 'every 10 seconds', not 'every 24 hours'.

Now, the thing is, that you either have a long (constantly) running  application, or you just have some code to execute every 24 hours. In the second case - you're better off with scheduler. In case of long-running application, I'd assume it actually does something besides waiting 24 hours a day, and then you can either use Timer, or have some way of leveraging the Scheduler (like via WCF - google: interprocess communication in .net or just via filesystem watcher maybe?)